# How do you place a list at the center of an image?

Tags: html, css

I want to put this list at the centre of the image, but I'm not sure how.

```
<html>
     <div>
     img src="url"
         <ul>
             <li>1</li>
             <li>2</li>
             <li>3</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</html>
```

I tried these styles, but each item of the list were clumped together.

```
<style>

    li {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
    ul {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: could you just make the div background the img?

Answer (score 3):

apply `position: relative` to the wrapping div. Then use `position: absolute; inset: 0;` on the `<ul>` to occupy the entire size of the parent element.

Te `<li>` can be center by using flexbox:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x200.jpg">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for the list, but now there is a black background over the image. Also, the text is aligned to the right.